# D3DX11CompileFromFile() function problem DirectX11

Tags: directx, directx11, c++

What do i have to include to use the `D3DX11CompileFromFile()` function on DirectX11? I'm using visual studio 2015 and reading the "3D Game programming guide" (Frank Luna) and i'm having problem using that function, any solutions?
I read online that is not usable anymore and that now i have to use the `D3DCompileFromFile()` function, but i have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D3DX11async.h`, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476261(v=vs.85).aspx). Note that the documentation also specifies the function is deprecated in Windows 8, and entirely usable in Windows store applications, and that may be why you are having trouble.

You should use [`D3DCompileFromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446872(v=vs.85).aspx) instead, as you've read on the internet. It's parameters are nearly identical to the set of parameters to `D3DX11CompileFromFile`, so with very few modifications you should be able to simply replace one with the other.

Comment: Josh Petrie♦ thanks for the help, i solved by using the D3DCompileFromFile function
I had to #include <d3dcompiler.h> to make it work